# how to check user is online or offline in socket.io nodejs?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to send notification when user is offline in socket.io. If user is online, then send normal messages.

```
 socket.on('201', (data) => {
    if (socket.request.user.logged_in === true) {
      sendNotification({ body:'hey' }, '123456');
   }
 });
```

Comment: please share code when user logs in and disconnects

Comment: Now i have solved this issue. Thank you so much guys for support. Keep coding and learn

Answer (score -1):

So you want to authenticate user, have a look at : https://www.npmjs.com/package/socketio-auth
It provides a way for token authentication.